# payment gateway integration in react native and node js project

Tags: node.js, react-native, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

so I want to integrate a payment gateway in my react native and nodejs project, it will be any of paypal or stripe. so basically we made a app sort of ecomerece where listers list there products and buyer buy, so the payment integration must be like when user buys a product from a specific retailer the payment must be transfer from user bank to retailer whose product is being brought by a user, is it possible to do so.

I say most of the youtube video where, all of them shows that the money will go to the admin/ whose credentials like secret key and public key from stripe are put into the code

I am expecting any document or anything that can help me with this

Comment: If you want to use Stripe, then you will have to use Stripe Connect and each of your retailer will need a Stripe account to receive the money. You can learn more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect).